# Unable to merge Swagger FOSRestBundle

Tags: api, annotations, swagger, symfony4

At first Google shows me only 2 sites results of my search. I have project in Symfony 4 and I use FOSRestBundle with autoconfigure routes. I also use NelmioApiDoc. With POST method everything is fine but when I need to use GET with specific route I guess Nelmio try to merge GET method with FOSRestBundle, but I dont use GET in NELMIO.

/api/doc shows me:
User Notice: Unable to merge @SWG\Get()

I have no idea to fix this issue.

This is my annotation in Controller.

```
 * @SWG\Tag(name="User")
 * @Security("is_granted('read', user)", message="Access denied.")
 * @Rest\Get("/api/users")
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. I needed to add generally definition of this route in SWG. In my opinion, swg should show something like: "SWG\Get missing declaration" but computer make mistakes too. :)

```
@SWG\Get( path="/api/path", summary="Confirm")
```